# Cannot select Combo box value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Combobox's where second one is dependent upon first one.

This means when the selectedindexchanged event of first Combobox fires, then the second Combobox will be enabled.
After Event Apply the second Combobox is loaded but I could not select the ComboBox Value

**How will i select the value??**
i used Dave express in c#
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried?

Comment: protected void ASPxComboModule_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LoadMenu();--2nd combo
                
            }

Answer (score 0):

On page load event load the first drop down list with data. On selected index changed event of first drop down list, get the selected text/value of the first drop down list and based on that load second drop down list with data. On selected index changed event of second dropdown keep brak point and check. See that you have given autopostback = 'true' for the drop down lists.

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Load first drop down list
}

protected void ASPxComboModule1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
//Load second drop down list based on first drop down selected text/value 
} 

protected void ASPxComboModule2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
//check whether this event gets fired if so then you are able to select values in your second drop down list
}
```