# Cannot select the ComboBox item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Comboboxes where the second one is dependent upon the first one.

When the SelectedIndexChanged event of the first Combobox fires then the second Combobox will be enabled.

After the event, the second Combobox is enabled but I cannot select the ComboBox item.

**EDIT**

I use Dev express Tools

First Combo I load in Page_Load Event

I use Server Side code:

```
protected void ASPxComboModule_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadSecondCombo();
    LoadSecondCombo.Focus();
}
```

There is no problem in loading, but I'm unable to select 2nd combo item.

Comment: protected void ASPxComboModule_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LoadSecondCombo();
                
                LoadSecondCombo.Focus();
            }

Comment: sigh, put it in the question, not as a comment. and that code doesnthelp. how are you binding items, whats in your page_load, etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [i couldnot select Combo box value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649350/i-couldnot-select-combo-box-value)

Comment: ya but problem is not solved yet

Comment: The fact you've never accepted an answer and the fact you've never answered a question makes it feel like you're leaching off the site, not contributing to the community.  If you want others to make an effort, you need to make an effort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What do this do: LoadSecondCombo();  I assume it returns an instance of the control.  Where does it set combo.Enabled at?

Answer (score 0):

```
LoadSecondCombo();     LoadSecondCombo.Focus();
```

look like method that reference your comboBox and Load it.
When you want to focus LoadSecondCombo  should ne an instance of Combo Box. I think it is not and so your combo is not selected.

Can you try going back a bit and look at the Id of combo Box (if it in a composit control like DataGrid / View you will have to do a FindControl) and then focus. I mean typing

```
comboBtn1.Focus();
```

Now if that works then you know that your control can be found. In that case mofidify the LoadSescondCombo() to return an instance of combo button if it is not doing so already.

then create a reference to that combobutton by

ComboButton cbtn = LoadSecondCombo(); and

cbtn.Focus();